# How to shadow Object.Equals() method in a Module?

Tags: .net, vb.net, module, equality, shadowing

Maybe the title of the question is not the proper, because the methods in a module cannot be shadowed, but In essence I want to shadow a base member declaring it again, and hidding it without loosing the opportunity to call it and return the proper value.

Normally I do this for Classes:

```
<EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)>
Public Shadows Function Equals(ByVal obj As Object) As Boolean
    Return MyBase.Equals(obj)
End Function
```

And this for Structures:

```
<EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)>
Public Shadows Function Equals(ByVal obj As Object) As Boolean
    Return Object.Equals(obj, Me)
End Function
```

The problem I find trying to reproduce this behavior with a module, is what I should use to fill the interrogant argument in the example below, since I can't use `Me`, the module name, or a constructor, I understand it, but what I need to use then?.

```
Module TestModule

    <EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)>
    Public Function Equals(ByVal obj As Object) As Boolean
        Return Object.Equals(obj, ?)
    End Function

End Module
```

Comment: What purpose would that serve if you are invoking the standard `Object.Equals`?

Comment: @Plutonix thanks for comment. The reason is just for design, I'm very capricious desiging classes, I like to see a Intellisense autocomplete box of my classes without base methods that I will never use in most scenarios, such as Equals or ReferenceEquals, I hide them for design, but I don't want to loose the ability to call them for efficiency.

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but it the VB Module concept is pretty much an IDE enforced concept.  If you apply `<Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.StandardModule> ` to a class in a class library (dll) that is not part of the current solution, you will see its `Shared` members appear as if they were in a VB Module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function, defined in Object, seems to be the one you are trying to shadow:

```
Public Overridable Function Equals (obj As Object) As Boolean
```

However this doesn't exist in a module.  The "Equals" you are seeing Intellisense suggest after your module name is the shared one:

```
Public Shared Function Equals (objA As Object, objB As Object) As Boolean
```

You can see them listed separately in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  To stop Intellisense suggesting it, just include this in your module:

```
<EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)> _
Public Function Equals(objA As Object, objB As Object) As Boolean
    Return Object.Equals(objA, objB)
End Function
```

It doesn't seem good design though

Comment: I just upgraded to Visual Studio 2015 and seems that now my question becomes non-sense because in this new IDE now the Equals and ReferenceEquals methods are not shown by Intellisense in modules (maybe they noted that those methods has any sense in a module), so I don't have to shadow anything now to hide them...

Comment: I can't turn back to VS2013 to verify what you've said about the shared function, I don't trust too much that all this time I was trying to shadow the wrong method, what a fail on my side if that is the case for didn't noticed the method signature difference properlly, anyways... I can't verify it but probablly would be true, then I just accept your answer. Thanks.

Comment: @ElektroStudios care to explain how this solved your problem, I am curious. The answer you accepted still lacks details about why you can't as I have explained...

Answer (score 2):

There are rules to this...and simply you can't.

You can use `Shadows` only at class level. This means the declaration context for a Shadows element must be a class, cannot be a source file, namespace, interface, **module**, structure, or procedure.

This is why you can in a structure and class...

Please see more [**here**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1h3wytf6.aspx). At the bottom it says what context the shadows can exist.

**Edit - Solution**

Not sure why you would want to invoke the `Object.Equals` at all when you can use the standard one ***or*** create your own function to determine if the two objects are equal.

Here is a simple solution that you can work off of that has been ***tried and tested***. Also if you want to use the `Equals` against many object, then again you would need to have more structures for what you are comparing against that would shadow the `Equals` function.

```
Module TestModule


    Sub Main()
        Dim a As New Person("Stack", "Overflow")
        Dim b As New Person("Stack", "Overflow")

        Console.WriteLine(a.Equals(b))

    End Sub

    Public Structure Person
        Private FirstName As String
        Private LastName As String

        Public Sub New(firstName As String, lastName As String)
            Me.FirstName = firstName
            Me.LastName = lastName
        End Sub

        <EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)>
        Public Shadows Function Equals(ByVal obj As Object) As String
            Return If(Object.Equals(obj, Me), "TRUE", "FALSE").ToString
        End Function
    End Structure

End Module
```

Now of course you may be wondering why the `Equals` returns a `String`, I purposely did this so you can see that it does shadow the base class as I am returning a different type, otherwise you can't. You can change that function to return a `Boolean` and change the return and it works just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but adding an structure to a module (a structure that will be empty and with no purpose in my case) is not what I have in mind. Currentlly I'm simulating the shadowing at module level just declaring the function with name "Equals", but I'm a little bit lost understanding in what manner I need to call the Object.Equals() inside (the second argument, which should be the module). I will try to inspect the online .Net Framework reference to try discover what Microsoft calls as second argument for **Object.Equals** to compare an object with a module. Really thanks anyways!